# Yammer Integeration with sharepoint using a WSP file

Tags: sharepoint-2010, user-permissions, yammer

I am trying to Integerate the Yammer with Sharepoint using the guide http://success.yammer.com/integrations/sharepoint/ and I am using the Online method of Integeration using a WSP file.

I uploaded the WSP file in the SP2010 Foundation and I am not able to Activate the Solution [image]

See I am getting the Inactive "Activate" Button...I predict the issue is with the permissions  some Mandatory Permissions which is needed for the user to activate a sand boxed Solution..Thanks in Advance for your Inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the sandboxed services is not running or is maybe not properly configured. I think you need to check if this is running. You can have a look here to see how to check if the user code service is turned on.

http://www.paulgrimley.com/2010/06/starting-sharepoint-2010-sandboxed-code.html